# Proving an inequality related to complex numbers.

Tags: complex-numbers

If $$\sum_{i=1}^4b_iz_i=0,\sum_{i=1}^4b_i=0,|z_i|=r$$ How can one prove that $$b_1b_2|z_1-z_2|^2=b_3b_4|z_3-z_4|$$

---

I tried LHS:
$$b_1b_2|z_1-z_2|^2=b_1b_2(z_1-z_2)(\bar z_1-\bar z_2)=b_1b_2(2r-z_1\bar z_2-z_2\bar z_1)$$

Comment: Are the $b_j$ real numbers (and the $z_j$ complex numbers)? (if not, takes $b_1=1$,$b_2=-1$, $b_3=i$, $b_4=-i$, and $z_1=i$, $z_2=1$, $z_3=-i$, $z_4=1$). Is it $|z_3-z_4|$, or its square ?

Comment: @Kelenner the problem may be stated partially, the b_j are real no. z_i complex and maybe,not surely the last term is squared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the $b_j$ are real numbers (if not, the example in my comment show a contradiction). Wlog, we can suppose that the $z_j$ are of modulus one.  Then taking the conjugate of the first equality, we get $b_1z_1^{-1}+b_2 z_2^{-1}+b_3z_3^{-1}+b_4 z_4^{-1}=0$.

Now write $b_1z_1+b_2z_2=-(b_3z_3+b_4z_4)$, $b_1z_1^{-1}+b_2z_2^{-1}=-(b_3z_3^{-1}+b_4z_4^{-1})$, and multiply these equality. We get that
$$b_1^2+b_2^2+2b_1b_2-2b_1b_2+b_1b_2z_1^{-1}z_2+b_1b_2z_1z_2^{-1}$$ is equal to 
$$b_3^2+b_4^2+2b_3b_4-2b_3b_4+b_3b_4z_3^{-1}z_4+b_3b_4z_3z_4^{-1}$$

Using
$$(b_1+b_2)^2=(b_3+b_4)^2$$
we get 
$$2b_1b_2-b_1b_2z_1^{-1}z_2-b_1b_2z_1z_2^{-1}=2b_3b_4-b_3b_4z_3^{-1}z_4-b_3b_4z_3z_4^{-1}$$
hence
$$b_1b_2|z_1-z_2|^2=b_3b_4|z_3-z_4|^2$$
and we are done.